# Regex (grok) - create general pattern for log which occurs but don't have to

Tags: regex, logstash, regex-group, logstash-grok

I am sorry for enigmatic topic title, but I did not know how to put it correctly.
These are log types:

```
{vpnclient} Client[10.10.10.10:54576](11764): sending R_KEYCHANGE message

{vpnclient} Client[10.10.10.10:54576](16031): sending R_IPCONFIG message - client IP = 172.11.11.11/255.255.255.0, CEP = 3600 s, DNS = 172.11.1.101, 172.11.1.102
```

And this is my grok pattern:

```
^{vpnclient} %{WORD}\[%{IP:[client][ip]}:%{NUMBER:[source][port]}\]\(%{INT:[process][pid]}\): %{GREEDYDATA:message} (:?%{GREEDYDATA:kv_vpn_message})
```

What i want to do is forward log after hyphen (so `- client IP`) to `kv` filter.
My problem is - this type of log does not occur always, so i want to wrap the whole grok pattern, so it matches until `%{GREEDYDATA:message}` and also `%{GREEDYDATA:kv_vpn_message}`, but only when it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^{vpnclient} %{WORD}\[%{IP:[client][ip]}:%{NUMBER:[source][port]}\]\(%{INT:[process][pid]}\): %{DATA:message}(?: - %{GREEDYDATA:kv_vpn_message})?$
```

There are several changes:

- `%{DATA:message}` - the `message` pattern is turned into a non-greedy dot pattern, `.*?`, with `GREEDYDATA` changed to `DATA`
- `(?: - %{GREEDYDATA:kv_vpn_message})?` - is an optional non-capturing group that matches one or zero occurrences of `-` and then zero or more chars as many as possible captured into the "kv_vpn_message" group
- `$` - end of string anchor, it allows the "message" `DATA` pattern match till the end of line.